# Get real user IP with PHP Ratchet Web socket server

Tags: php, websocket, ratchet, phpwebsocket

I have been using PHP Ratchet with Stunnel for SSL. It's working well. But the problem is, I can't get users real IP address.

I already tried these

```
$conn->remoteAddress
```

and with this I am getting 127.0.0.1 (local address)

```
$conn->WebSocket->request->getHeader('X-Forwarded-For');
```

and with this I am getting nothing.

Any help!

Comment: I guess you have to forward the client IP in Stunnel

Comment: How is that possible, Can you suggest?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Stunnel, but if this is the reason it's for sure a configuration thing.

Comment: I'm not even using Stunnel and I'm getting the same issue. `$conn->remoteAddress` returns the server's address instead of the client.

Answer (score 2):

Or sometimes it's `$conn->httpRequest->getHeaders()['X-Forwarded-For'][0]`.

Answer (score 1):

This is really old, but I ran into it just now.

You're looking for `$conn->WebSocket->request->getHeader('x-forwarded-for)` or `$conn->WebSocket->request->getHeader('x-real-ip')`.

See `$conn->WebSocket->request->getHeaders()` for the entire list.